# Submitting a form Firebase for details of a Product with an array of multiple images with getDownloadURL and setting to State (productThumbnail)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, forms, redux, react-hooks

Going into the debugger of the developer tools shows 2 problems:

1. Cannot read property .then of undefined
2. It also shows that the TWO files are being 'put' to storage 2 separate instances, which I believe causes the dispatch addProductStart to also run twice.
   moving the setProductThumbnail((prevState)... down a line removes the .then undefined error, but also results in addProductStart running twice. Resulting in 2 products being made instead of 1 product with multiple images.

So to solve this, the handleSubmit function needs to be refactored to where getDownloadURL is able to put 2 URLs into an array, and set to State productThumbnail, so that products can be uploaded with multiple images attached in Firestore Collection

````
const productImgHandler = (e) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
            const selectedFiles = e.target.files[i];
            selectedFiles["id"] = Math.random();
            setpreProductThumbnail((prevState) => [
                ...prevState,
                selectedFiles,
            ]);
            console.log(selectedFiles);
        }
    };
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        const promises = [];
        e.preventDefault();
        preproductThumbnail.map((image) => {
            promises.push(storage().ref(`prodimages/${image.name}`).put(image));
            storage()
                .ref(`prodimages/${image.name}`)
                .put(image)
                .on(
                    "state_changed",
                    (snapshot) => {
                        const progress =
                            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) *
                            100;
                        console.log(progress);
                    },
                    (err) => {
                        setError(err.message);
                    },
                    
                     () => {
                         storage()
                            .ref("prodimages")
                            .child(image.name)
                            .getDownloadURL()
                            setProductThumbnail((prevState) => [...prevState, productThumbnail])
                            .then((productThumbnail) => { // put an array in here, then change fetch function on Productpage
                                    console.log("PRODTHUMB2", productThumbnail);

                                dispatch(
                                    addProductStart({
                                        productCategory,
                                        productName,
                                        productThumbnail,
                                        productPrice,
                                        productDesc,
                                    })
                                );
                            }, resetForm());
                    }
                );
        });```
````

Answer (score 1):

`setProductThumbnail` does not return a promise to then `.then()` promise chain onto.
You should be processing the `setProductThumbnail` inside the `.then()` statement instead.

Comment: Okay thanks, so I did this, however now the problem is that uploading multiple photos still results in the productThumbnail hook being assigned only 1 item in the array.

Comment: So the function loops through each photo uploaded, instead of just putting the URLs of each photo into an array [] and setting to productThumbnail

Comment: I find from the debugger that when Snapshot Progress is completed for 1 image, it goes onto the next function Dispatch without completing the previous file upload, so I probably need to move a ) or } or set a condition for all files being fully uploaded